# I want to do validate product id is exist in db or not . I am learning to devlope REST API in Php

Tags: php, mysql, rest

I am trying to check product id is exits in database or not. Help me to correct if condition . What condition i have to check? update() query is defined

```
$product = new Product($db);
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$product->id = $data->id;  
$product->name = $data->name;  
$product->price = $data->price; 
$product->description = $data->description;  
$product->category_id = $data->category_id;

$ok=$product->update();

if($ok==$data->id){ 

    http_response_code(200);

    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Product was updated.."));
} else {

    http_response_code(503);  

    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to update product"));
}
```

below is update() function code

```
function update(){

// update query
$query = "UPDATE
            " . $this->table_name . "
        SET
            name = :name,
            price = :price,
            description = :description,
            category_id = :category_id
        WHERE
            id = :id";
```

}

Comment: Are you using some ORM? Is the `->update();` something you want us to magically code for you? Where's the loop (and there's no need)?  Suggest `UPDATE products SET ..... WHERE ID = ?", data-$id` If the number of updated rows is 0, nothing was found.

Comment: tHIS IS my update()                                                                                            
         $query = "UPDATE
                " . $this->table_name . "
            SET
                name = :name,
                price = :price,
                description = :description,
                category_id = :category_id
            WHERE
                id = :id";

Comment: Great. Edit the question to include the full implementation. Feel free to edit the text of your question too. Non-bold text actually reads better.  Look at the text too, its a bit unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You `update()` appears to be setting a variable only. Show its implementation in the question.